# Compare nested list and group lists having similar nth element

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a list which has multiple nested list. I want to iterate through those nested lists and if the third element is same on the nested lists, then I want to group those nested list, in a separate list.

Input :

```
[['10', '1', 'SELL', 'toaster_1', '10.00', '20'], ['12', '8', 'BID', 'toaster_1', '7.50'], ['13', '5', 'BID', 'toaster_1', '12.50'], ['15', '8', 'SELL', 'tv_1', '250.00', '20'], ['16'], ['17', '8', 'BID', 'toaster_1', '20.00'], ['18', '1', 'BID', 'tv_1', '150.00'], ['19', '3', 'BID', 'tv_1', '200.00'], ['20'], ['21', '3', 'BID', 'tv_1', '300.00']]
```

Desired Output :

```
Toaster List = [['10', '1', 'SELL', 'toaster_1', '10.00', '20'], ['12', '8', 'BID', 'toaster_1', '7.50'], ['13', '5', 'BID', 'toaster_1', '12.50'], ['17', '8', 'BID', 'toaster_1', '20.00']]

TV List = [['15', '8', 'SELL', 'tv_1', '250.00', '20'], ['18', '1', 'BID', 'tv_1', '150.00'], ['19', '3', 'BID', 'tv_1', '200.00'], ['21', '3', 'BID', 'tv_1', '300.00']]
```

I then can do processing of auction on these lists.

I am unable to separate them based on the auction item names. I have spent looking at multiple sites but not able to find any answer, can someone guide me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea is to have a `dict` as a result

**Ex:**

```
data = [['10', '1', 'SELL', 'toaster_1', '10.00', '20'], ['12', '8', 'BID', 'toaster_1', '7.50'], ['13', '5', 'BID', 'toaster_1', '12.50'], ['15', '8', 'SELL', 'tv_1', '250.00', '20'], ['16'], ['17', '8', 'BID', 'toaster_1', '20.00'], ['18', '1', 'BID', 'tv_1', '150.00'], ['19', '3', 'BID', 'tv_1', '200.00'], ['20'], ['21', '3', 'BID', 'tv_1', '300.00']]
result = {}
for i in data:
    if len(i) > 3:
        result.setdefault(i[3], []).append(i)
    
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
{'toaster_1': [['10', '1', 'SELL', 'toaster_1', '10.00', '20'],
               ['12', '8', 'BID', 'toaster_1', '7.50'],
               ['13', '5', 'BID', 'toaster_1', '12.50'],
               ['17', '8', 'BID', 'toaster_1', '20.00']],
 'tv_1': [['15', '8', 'SELL', 'tv_1', '250.00', '20'],
          ['18', '1', 'BID', 'tv_1', '150.00'],
          ['19', '3', 'BID', 'tv_1', '200.00'],
          ['21', '3', 'BID', 'tv_1', '300.00']]}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood your question right, but you can use simple filtering list-comprehension:

```
lst = [['10', '1', 'SELL', 'toaster_1', '10.00', '20'], ['12', '8', 'BID', 'toaster_1', '7.50'], ['13', '5', 'BID', 'toaster_1', '12.50'], ['15', '8', 'SELL', 'tv_1', '250.00', '20'], ['16'], ['17', '8', 'BID', 'toaster_1', '20.00'], ['18', '1', 'BID', 'tv_1', '150.00'], ['19', '3', 'BID', 'tv_1', '200.00'], ['20'], ['21', '3', 'BID', 'tv_1', '300.00']]


toaster_list = [l for l in lst if len(l) > 3 and l[3] == 'toaster_1']
tv_list = [l for l in lst if len(l) > 3 and l[3] == 'tv_1']

print(toaster_list)
print(tv_list)
```

Prints:

```
[['10', '1', 'SELL', 'toaster_1', '10.00', '20'], ['12', '8', 'BID', 'toaster_1', '7.50'], ['13', '5', 'BID', 'toaster_1', '12.50'], ['17', '8', 'BID', 'toaster_1', '20.00']]
[['15', '8', 'SELL', 'tv_1', '250.00', '20'], ['18', '1', 'BID', 'tv_1', '150.00'], ['19', '3', 'BID', 'tv_1', '200.00'], ['21', '3', 'BID', 'tv_1', '300.00']]
```

Comment: thank you Andrej, the code works perfectly fine. But I do not have the auction items name (toaster and tv) with me before hand. It will be passed in runtime. Sorry I am new to python. I created another list to name all the auction items. Is there anyway I can use that list to do the above?

Comment: @user6662097 I'm now on mobile, but Rakesh's answer is good - create a dictionary where keys will be your names and values will be list of items.

Comment: Thank you Andrej!